# Prove that $E=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[d]{a})$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, normed-spaces, extension-field, cyclic-groups

> Let $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[n]{a})$, where $a \in \Bbb Q^+$ and suppose $[K:\Bbb Q]=n$ (i.e., $x^n-a$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$). Let $E$ be any subfield of $K$ and let $[E:\Bbb Q]=d$. Prove that $E=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[d]{a})$.

Now $N_{K/F}(\sqrt[n]{a})=a\in \Bbb Q$. I also know that $N_{K/E}(\sqrt[n]{a})\in  E$. What I have observed is $K/\Bbb Q$ need not be cyclic as the $n$th root of unity is not in $\Bbb Q$. So what to do next? I am clueless here.

**Edit.** In the comment I got some help considering the Galois closure of $K$. The Galois closure will be $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n,\sqrt[n]{a})$ which has cyclic Galois group $\Bbb Z_n$ over $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n)$.  Now if $Gal(K(\zeta_n)/\Bbb Q)=\left<f\right> \cong \Bbb Z_n$ then $Gal(K(\zeta_n)/E(\zeta_n))=\left<f^d\right>$. So the element that will be fixed by $f^d$ is $\sqrt[n]{a}+f^d(\sqrt[n]{a})+\cdots + f^{(n/d)-1}(\sqrt[n]{a})=\sqrt[n]{a}+\zeta_n^d\sqrt[n]{a}+\cdots + \zeta_n^{(n/d)-1}\sqrt[n]{a}$. But is it $\sqrt[d]{a}$?

Comment: Think about the Galois closure of $K$?

Comment: The Galois closure will be $\Bbb Q(\zeta_n,\sqrt[n]{a})$.

Comment: Do you know the Galois group of the Galois closure as an extension of the rationals? If so, you can use Galois Theory to find all the fields between the Galois closure and the rationals, so, in particular, all the fields between $K$ and the rationals.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I need more clue

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Say $n=6$, $d=3$. I don't see why c=$b+f(b)+f^2(b)$ [I'm abbreviating $\root n\of a$ to $b$] should be fixed by $f^2$. Applying $f^2$ gives $f^2(b)+f^3(b)+f^4(b)\ne c$. And I don't see how one element can qualify as an answer to the question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson will it $\sqrt[n]{a}+f^d(\sqrt[n]{a})+\cdots +f^{(n/d-1)d}(\sqrt[n]{a})$ as this will be fixed by $<f^{d}>$, where $Gal(K(\zeta_n)/\Bbb Q)=<f>$?. I think i am baffled after doing a lot of Galois problems in a day.

Comment: @GerryMyerson for $n=6,d=3$ $c=b+f^3(b)$ then $f^3(c)=c$ now I have edited my question and there why would it be $\sqrt[d]a$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I have progressed whatever I can do, now please help me.

Comment: Does the answer to the duplicate target help you enough? If there is a difference I missed, or you want to ask about a specific step, do edit! Reverting the duplicate closure is as easy as the closure.

Comment: +1 for showing how you might go about it. The Galois group $Gal(K(\zeta_n)/\Bbb{Q})$ is more complicated than what you described. You get $Gal(K(\zeta_n),\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n))\simeq\Bbb{Z}_n$ instead. What may also happen is that $Gal(K(\zeta_n)/K)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$, but there are corner cases.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/204552/11619) for a full account of the bigger Galois group.

Comment: And [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1316908/11619) for another incarnation of this question. A case can be made for selecting this as the duplicate target instead.

Comment: I should keep this problem as unknowingly I was stuck at a good problem. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Don't worry about it too much. Searching on this site is not easy unless you know a few tools. [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5CBbb%20Q(%5Csqrt%5Bd%5D%7Ba%7D)%24%2C%20subfield&p=1) helped.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen can you also help me here "https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3209005/which-subfields-of-the-galois-group-of-x48x28x4-are-galois-and-find-the-s"?